# How can I resize a UITableView without resizing a View inside it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `Tableview` that has a `UIView` and a label inside each row, and this `UITableView` resize its rows using

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Well, my problem is that when I resize the cell, its view is resized automatically too. How can I avoid resizing the view inside the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `autoresizesSubviews` of your cells prevents any subviews within your cells to resize automatically. By setting it at `NO`, it should fix your problem.

```
cell.autoresizingMask = NO;
```

However, I would suggest using the method below when playing with the size of cells.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You should set a proper autoresizing mask or autolayouts rules of the cell subviews, to obtain the layout you want for your cells

Answer (score -1):

you can set the label's contentMode.

for example:

UILabel *lb...(create)

lb.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleToFill (change that ,)
  cell addSubView:lb;